# Start ssh session on remote hosts with local bash rc file

Tags: bash, ssh, alias, openssh

Is it possible somehow to source a specific bashfile right at the start of each ssh session on a foreign host? I have a file with just aliases that I want to use on foreign hosts as well as on my local machine. Now I'm fully aware that not all commands might be available on the foreign host, still my aliases usually only wrap very basic things like `ls -al | grep $1`, so I think that there's no harm, however the internet tells me that I always need to create a seperate `.bashrc` file on every host (which I can't or won't do because the whole company uses the same user on the external machine and I don't want to force my aliases up anyone's throat).

What's the least cumbersome way to achieve this?

Comment: The alias definitions don't have to be in `.bashrc`, but if they are in any other file you are going to have to source that file explicitly.  Are you allowed to leave a copy of the file containing your alias definitions on the remote host(s), or would you need to re-upload it every time you connect?

Comment: If you can leave a file on the remote hosts, you could have that source the "real" `.bashrc` file, as well as do your own personal configuration, then use `ssh user@host 'bash --rcfile my_config'`, telling `bash` to use an alternate configuration file instead of the remote `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Aliases don't usefully work with arguments like `$1`, which is one of the many, many reasons to prefer functions.

Comment: That is to say, your `ls -al | grep $1` alias would behave just the same way in most cases if you changed it to `ls -al | grep`; aliases are just prefix expansion, so the only reason the `$1` isn't _actively harmful_ is because usually in an interactive shell the argument list is empty; but as soon as someone runs `set -- one two three` in your shell, then your if you have `alias lsgrep='ls -al | grep $1'`, `lsgrep foo` will expand to `ls -al | grep one foo`, with the word `one` coming from `$1` and the `foo` just being appended to the results of the prefix expansion like it always is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your remote login shell is also Bash —

First, define this in your local Bash shell:

```bash
#
# update it per your requirement
#
function rcssh()
{
    local rcfile=$1
    local dest=$2
    local rc=$( < "$rcfile" )

    printf -v rc '%q' "$rc"
    ssh -t $dest "bash --rcfile <( printf '%s\n' $rc )"
}
```

Next, save all your aliases (and other bashrc stuff) in a local file, say `myrcfile` <sup>(suppose it's not too big)</sup>:

```bash
echo 'Loading local rc on remote ...'

alias foo='echo hello foo'

function bar()
{
   echo hello bar
}

echo 'Loading local rc on remote ... done'

#
# if you also want to load some remote rcfile
#
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, run like this:

```
[local] $ rcssh myrcfile user@server
Loading local rc on remote ...
Loading local rc on remote ... done
bash-3.2$ foo
hello foo
bash-3.2$ bar
hello bar
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: `printf '%s' "$rc"`. Word-splitting on `$rc` won't just produce a separate argument per line, but a separate argument per *word*, as well as being subject to globbing.

Comment: i did a `printf %q` before that.

Comment: Ah, I did miss that.

Comment: Works nice, thx. I made the function automatically append the `source ~/.bashrc` so I could also source myrcfile from my local .bashrc